# Looping through an array and create from each key an HTML anchor in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, get, skeleton-code

New at PHP, for college I got a skeleton with a basic assignment: I have to make an assosciate array with 3 people and their age, I then have to loop that array (foreach) and make an HTML anchor/link for every key.  Every anchor/link influences what is between the *if (isset($_GET['name'])*

This is the associate array ($age)

```
$age['Atticus'] ="2100";
$age['McDunna'] ="96";
$age['Oberon']  ="13";
```

What can I change/add in this "loop" so that they influences what is between the *if (isset($_GET['name'])*

```
foreach ($age as $key => $value) {
    echo "<a href=\"GET\">'$key'</a>";
            echo "<br>";
```

I have also concidered to let the array create a form from each key so that I can use *form method =get* but I'm not too sure this is possible.

This is my first question, so I am sorry if some parts are confusing, I will gladly clear something up.  If it is easier I can provide the skeleton-code:

```
<?php

 // TODO make an assoc array with 3 people and their age.; 


if( isset( $_GET['name']) ){

// TODO create a text with the name and age; 
    $infoText= "$age";



$infoText =  NULL; 
}else{

// TODO create  generic text.; 

}
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

 </head>

<body>

    <header>
        <?php
            // TODO "Loop" the $age array. and  for every key  create an HTML anchor/link.;
        foreach ($age as $key => $value) {
                 echo "<a href=\"GET\">'$key'</a>";
                 echo "<br>";
        }

        ?>

    </header>

    <h3><?php // TODO display the infoText ?></h3>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<?php

 // TODO make an assoc array with 3 people and their age.; 
$age['Atticus'] = 2100;
$age['McDunna'] = 96;
$age['Oberon']  = 13; 
$infoText = 'Not selected';
if (isset( $_GET['name']) ){
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    if(array_key_exists($name, $age)) {
        $infoText = 'Name: ' .$name . ' Age: '. $age[$name]; // Name: John Age: 27
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
<body>

    <header>
        <?php
            // TODO "Loop" the $age array. and  for every key  create an HTML anchor/link.;
        foreach ($age as $key => $value) {
                 echo "<a href=\"?name=".$key."\">".$key."</a>";
                 echo "<br>";
        }

        ?>

    </header>

    <h3><?php echo $infoText; ?></h3>

</body>
```